# Hide module from custom user group

Tags: joomla-3.x, user, user-groups

How I can hide module from custom Joomla group? I want module to be visible for registered users but hide it from paid 'premium' registered users.

Comment: You can use Joomla ACL for this.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new Access Level for your site, from here you can
 control which users can view which objects on your site, like modules.

You can create your new access level in **Users** > **Access Level**

Now, assign to your user group the new access level, then that users 
can view the modules assigned to this access level.

In your modules you can see an option for Access Level:
Regards!.
[image: Access Level - Joomla! 3]